# React native expo play protect unknown developer

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play-protect

I have developed an Android application with React Native and Expo, which uses the following accesses:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

My app is also signed correctly, but when I install it, I get an error like the image below:

[image: Play Protect unknown developer message]

All the addresses that I have in my application are on the https protocol. I have filled out and submitted the [protectappeals](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals) form several times, but I still haven't received an email! I am really confused where the problem is!
This is my app download address:
https://expo.dev/artifacts/eas/qGh7YryQS97nMX1Kxz5ybk.apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to introduce the application to Google or usually this error will disappear after several times of installation

Comment: Thanks, I don't get this error anymore, I think filling out the google form solved the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).